# Django - Rendering tooltips stored in the database in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building a Django site and in various places I want to display a little question mark and if the user hovers over it, it should display a message. I think the best approach is to store the tooltip in the database like this:

```
class Tooltip(models.Model):
    key = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    message = models.Charfield(max_length=300)
```

My question is what is the best way to get the tooltips in the templates? So far my idea is to create a custom template tag, which will do the lookup and return the result, but I haven't used template tags much and wondering if there is a problem with this approach?

```
{% tooltip 'message_key' %}
```

Comment: Usually tooltip is somethig that will never change and is unique for every situation, so: Do you really need to store this in DB? Is not possible write it directly in your template?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I guess it makes a lot more sense. Simpler is always better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django documentation [explains how to create template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Could be as simple as:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tooltip(key):
    try:
        tooltip = Tooltip.objects.get(key=key)
        return tooltip.message
    except Tooltip.DoesNotExist:
        return ''  # or return a message stating that the key does not exist.
```

You need to save this file in your app's `templatetags/` directory, along with an `__init__.py`. You can then `{% load "<appname>" %}` in your template and use the tag like you suggested.

While you might not need a database to store these, if you do, at least [add an index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#db-index) to the `key` field on your model.